# Show data backwards with PHP

Tags: php

I have a code production as you can see below.
I connect to database, pull user's data if day and month are equal to today.
I want to bring the data of not only today, but also 1 week retrospectively, including today.
So like this;
Today is 30.05.20222. I want today's data for the dates 29.05,28.05,27.05,26.05,25.05,24.05,23.05 to appear just below.

```php
$VerileriGetir = $db->query("SELECT  * FROM data ")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($VerileriGetir as $key => $value) {

    $DbGelenTarih = $value['1'];
    $GuncelGunAy = new DateTime($DbGelenTarih);
    $veri5 = array($GuncelGunAy->format('d.m.y'));

    $Tarih= date("d").".".date("m").".".date("y");

    if($veri5[0] == $Tarih){

        $veri[] = array(
            "1" => $value['1'],
            "2" => $value['2'],
            "3" => $value['3']
        );
    }      
}
```

Comment: You mean `ORDER BY id DESC`? Or if your date has another sort than your `id` you can use `ORDER BY dateColumn DESC`.

Comment: @Martijn I can't use this as the dates will change every day. I think this can be solved with the strtotime command, but I could not integrate it into my system.

Comment: Your code have a a logic mistake. You try to access the $value[n] inside the foreach loop.

Comment: Instead of filtering out results that don't match your condition while you are looping over the data, you should much rather limit what records your SQL query returns to begin with, by adding a WHERE clause to it.

Answer (score 0):

There a few ways here. In case they are added in the same order:

```
$VerileriGetir = $db->query("SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY id DESC")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

where "id" is the primary key of your table.

In case they are not added in same order then you can order by "date"

```
$VerileriGetir = $db->query("SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY date DESC")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

As for a php way, you can add "array_reverse" in your code something like:

```
    foreach ($VerileriGetir as $key => $value) {
        $DbGelenTarih = $value['1'];
        $GuncelGunAy = new DateTime($DbGelenTarih);
        $veri5 = array($GuncelGunAy->format('d.m.y'));
    
        $veri5 = array_reverse($veri5);
    
        $Tarih= date("d").".".date("m").".".date("y");
    
        if($veri5[0] == $Tarih){
    
            $veri[] = array(
                "1" => $value['1'],
                "2" => $value['2'],
                "3" => $value['3']
            );
        }
    }
```

For a more clear answer, you can also update your question and add the result of your query so we can understand how your db is structured.